# How does the play_again work when the start isnt defined yet? I cant get it to work at "fällan rum"

Tags: python

(unimportant)

```
import random
x = random.randint(0,3)
```

How can start be defined here but I can't get it defined under "Fällan rum"?

```
def play_again():
  print("\nDo you want to play again? (y or n)")
  
  # convert the player's input to lower_case
  answer = input(">").lower()

  if "y" in answer:
    # if player typed "yes" or "y" start the game from the beginning
    start()
  else:
    # if user types anything besides "yes" or "y", exit() the program
    exit()

# game_over function accepts an argument called "reason"
def game_over(reason):
  # print the "reason" in a new line (\n)
  print("\n" + reason)
  print("Game Over!")
  # ask player to play again or not by activating play_again() function
  play_again()

# Fällan rum
def Fällan_rum():
  # some prompts
  # '\n' is to print the line in a new line
  print("\nPrecis när du tar ett kliv in i det mörka rummet så uptäcker du att det inte finns 

ett golv!")
      print("Du börjar falla ned i mörkret.\nVill du försöka ta tag i dörrkarmen eller hoppas du att fallet blir kort och att du klarar dig? Vad gör du? (1 or 2)")
      print("1). Försöker greppa tag i dörrkarmen.")
      print("2). Hoppas att fallet blir kort och att du klarar dig!")
    
      # take input()
    answer = input(">")
    if answer == "1" and x==3:
        # the player is dead!
        ("The bear killed you.")
    elif answer == "2" and x==3:
        # lead him to the start()
        print("\nNice")
#Why cant i go back to the start from here?
        start()
    else:
        # else call game_over() function with the "reason" argument
        game_over("Don't you know how to type a number?")
    
    def start():
      # give some prompts.
      print("\nDu står utanför ett stort nedgånget hus.")
      print("Du kliver in i huset och ser tre dörrar. En dörr åt höger en dörr rakt fram och en dörr på vänster sida, vilken dörr går du in i? (h eller v eller f)")
      
      # convert the player's input() to lower_case
      answer = input(">").lower()
    
      if "h" in answer:
        # if player typed "left" or "l" lead him to bear_room()
        bear_room()
      elif "v" in answer:
        # else if player typed "right" or "r" lead him to monster_room()
        monster_room()
    
      elif "f" in answer:
          Fällan_rum()
    
      else:
        # else call game_over() function with the "reason" argument
        game_over("Don't you know how to type something properly?")
    # start the game

start()
```

Comment: Can you look into the indentation? I may have made some inadvertent changes.

Comment: The definition of `start()` is indented, so it's only defined locally within `Fällan_rum()`